# How to set auto-refresh on/off using button in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I was bit worry about the auto-refresh functionality in angular js. I tried with time-out concept.It worked page was refreshing for time interval what I set.

```
app.controller('buildCtrl', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
dataService.getAppData($scope.periodData).success(function(response) {
      $scope.loading = false;
      bc.serviceGridData = response.appdata;
      $scope.data = response.appdata;
      $timeout(function() {
          dataService.getAppData($scope.periodData);
          $state.reload();
      }, 20000)
}
}]);
```

Now, I need a button to enable and disable (on/off) this $timeout functionality.If it is on the page need to refresh if it is off page should not refresh.The time interval needs to clear.

Can you please help me on this.How a single button can work to set this on/off functionality.
    Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use `$timeout.cancel()` on your off button. ti will cancel the associated task with timeout

Comment: Then i need to have two buttons for on and off but i want it to be done with single button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module( 'app', [ ] );

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope,$timeout ) {
 
  
 $scope.StartTimeOut=false;
  $scope.ON_Off=function(isOn)
  {
    
    if(isOn)
    {
      alert("true")
    }
    else
    {
      alert("false")
    }
  }
 
  
} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
   
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <input type="button" value="Click" ng-click=ON_Off(StartTimeOut=!StartTimeOut) />
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can write your timeout code in `if` and `else` part of function.